# Zonal Computing Olympiad 2015, 29 Nov 2014 Problem

Tags: python, python-3.x

Need help regarding this question. [This is the problem](https://www.codechef.com/ZCOPRAC/problems/ZCO15002/)

> We say that two integers x and y have a variation of at least K, if |x
>   − y| ≥ K (the absolute value of their difference is at least K). Given
>   a sequence of N integers a1,a2,...,aN and K, the total variation count
>   is the number of pairs of elements in the sequence with variation at
>   least K, i.e. it is the size of the set of pairs
>
> ```
> {(i,j)|1≤i<j≤N and|ai−aj|≥K}
> ```
>
> For example if K = 1 and the sequence is 3,2,4 the answer is 3. If K =
>   1 and the sequence is 3, 1, 3 then the answer is 2.
>
> Your task is to write a program that takes a sequence and the value K
>   as input and computes the total variation count.
>
> **Input format**
>
> The first line contains two positive integers N and K, separated by a
>   space.
>
> This is followed by a line containing N integers separated by space
>   giving the values of the sequence.
>
> **Output format**
>
> A single integer in a single line giving the total variation count.
>
> **Test data**
>
> You may assume that all integers in the input are in the range 0 to
>   10^8 inclusive.
>
> ```
> Subtask 1 (40 marks) : 1 ≤ N ≤ 4000, 1 ≤ K ≤ 10^8
>
> Subtask 2 (60 marks) : 1 ≤ N ≤ 65000, 1 ≤ K ≤ 10^8
> ```

I'm using a `O(n)` solution for this still I'm not able to pass the advanced test cases. Could you please point out how it's taking long execution time for some test cases and more importantly how can this be resolved.

```
n,k=map(int,input().split())
li=list(map(int,input().split()))
count=0
li.sort()
i=0
j=1
while(i<n and j<n):
    if(abs(li[i]-li[j])>=k):
        count+=(n-j)
        i+=1
        j=i+1
    else:
        j+=1
print(count)
```

Answer (score 0):

You solution is most definitively **NOT** `O(n)` because you are using `list.sort()`, which has a time complexity of `O(n log n)` (it uses [`Timsort`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort) internaly).

---

As far as I can tell, your approach seems reasonable. Just a few improvement tips:

- use a temp variable (`elem_i`) to hold `num_list[i]`, so you don't need to do so many list lookups.
- since you sort the list, you can omit the call to `abs()` by rearanging your two variable (element `j` will always be greater or equal to `i`).

Here is your (`f1()`) and my (`f2()`) version of the code; it is written as functions so I can benchmark them:

```
def f1(num_list, k):
    num_list.sort()
    n = len(num_list)

    count = 0
    i = 0
    j = 1
    while i < n and j < n:
        if abs(num_list[i] - num_list[j]) >= k:
            count += (n-j)
            i += 1
            j = i + 1
        else:
            j += 1

    return count

def f2(num_list, k):
    num_list.sort()
    n = len(num_list)

    count = 0
    i = 0
    j = i + 1
    elem_i = num_list[i]

    while i < n and j < n:
        if num_list[j] - elem_i >= k:
            count += (n - j)
            i += 1
            j = i + 1
            elem_i = num_list[i]
        else:
            j += 1

    return count
```

Benchmarking my code:

```
import timeit
import random

for n in [1000, 4000, 10000]:
    numbers = [random.randint(0, 10**8) for _ in range(n)]

    for k in [10**1, 10**3, 10**5, 10**7]:
        t1 = timeit.timeit(
            'f(numbers, k)', 'from __main__ import numbers, k, f1 as f',
            number=10)
        t2 = timeit.timeit(
            'f(numbers, k)', 'from __main__ import numbers, k, f2 as f',
            number=10)

        print('n {:10,d} | k {:10,d} | {:10.4f} | {:10.4f} | best f{}'.format(
            n, k, t1, t2, '1' if t1 < t2 else '2'))
        assert f1(numbers, k) == f2(numbers, k)
```

gives me these results:

```
n      1,000 | k         10 |     0.0026 |     0.0020 | best f2
n      1,000 | k      1,000 |     0.0026 |     0.0020 | best f2
n      1,000 | k    100,000 |     0.0044 |     0.0033 | best f2
n      1,000 | k 10,000,000 |     0.1585 |     0.0919 | best f2
n      4,000 | k         10 |     0.0102 |     0.0074 | best f2
n      4,000 | k      1,000 |     0.0097 |     0.0076 | best f2
n      4,000 | k    100,000 |     0.0365 |     0.0243 | best f2
n      4,000 | k 10,000,000 |     2.3722 |     1.3992 | best f2
n     10,000 | k         10 |     0.0255 |     0.0190 | best f2
n     10,000 | k      1,000 |     0.0260 |     0.0194 | best f2
n     10,000 | k    100,000 |     0.1938 |     0.1190 | best f2
n     10,000 | k 10,000,000 |    15.2469 |     9.0770 | best f2
```

It is not much improvement, but it is something. I don't know if it helps you, though.

Comment: @EXODIA I added a slightly faster version in my answer